# Flutter Scaffold allow child behind the system Navigation Bar

Tags: android, flutter

I post this question due to the difficult to find the response I need, but I guess it must have been replied somewhere. If it indeed was asked and replied somewhere else, please point me to the right direction

See the image below, taken from a kitkat device. The Scaffold has a red background, and it's body a green one. I need the green to cover all scaffold, including the area behind the Navigation Bar.

[image: Scaffold = red, Scaffold's Body = green]

Ps.: Code, as requested

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Center(

        ),
    ),
      // Set bg to blue, to show that the Scaffold is indeed behind the Nav Bar...
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Ps².: To make things clear, my problem is that I'm trying to draw behind the Navigation Bar. The Scaffold clearly draws itself behind it, but it doesn't let me do this, and if I use `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);` the Navigation Bar is hidden, and I need it to be visible, like the Status Bar is.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @SaeedMasoumi added as requested.

Comment: @joaoBeno do you fix?

Comment: @EgosZhang I didn't try any of the later replies due to time constraints... I will try them either today or tomorrow, and accept a reply that fix the issue... In the meantime, you can try these answers yourself and see if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Stack` widget, to make the container cover the scaffold.

read here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

you can write something like this

```
Stack(
  children: [
     Scaffold(...),
     Container(..., height: double.infinity, width: double.infinity),
  ]
)
```

The container should cover the scaffold since it's sitting on top of it :)

Comment: This didn't do the trick... The Scaffold always reserve a space at the bottom for the Navigation Bar...

Comment: AH I remember now, the Scaffold has a `backgroundColor` property, set that to `Colors.transparent`

Answer (score 0):

You must center your container not warping your `Center` with `Container` widget.

```dart
Center(
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
);
```

By [defualt](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html), `Center` widget will match it's child size.

Comment: The problem is not with center, as even if you set the width and height to match the screen, the `Scaffold` always reserve a space at the bottom for the Navigation Bar...

Comment: @joaoBeno This code works for me, What is your device model?

Answer (score 0):

Adding: `extendBody: true,` on Scaffold works here. Body will extend under bottomNavigationBar.